# java alternative backup rotation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, rotation, backup

I am beginner in the world of rotation algorithms. I need to enhance an already existing backup algorithm written in Java which takes care of backing up databases and archiving them. An important aspect of this algorithm is that it reads an INI file where you can specify which days of the week the user wants to back up their databases.

E.g. like this:
`ScheduledWeekDaysAct=MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI`
or
`ScheduledWeekDaysAct=TUE, FRI`

So, the rotation algorithm has to take into account that backups can be created on all combinations of days. That means I can't use a Grandfather-father-son algorithm easily, that I already implemented. Because what I coded expects that backups get created on each day of the year and that would not be compatible with the backing up code.

For this problem there is an algorithm idea, a not too elaborate expected behaviour, which is the following:

- The first 10 (ten) most recent backup should always be kept.
- After the most recent ten is kept, the rest older should be thinned. Not piece by piece, but by datetime. The date of the 10th oldest backup is a designated reference date, to which the older backups will be compared upon a new backup happens. Older backups should be kept and thinned something like the following.
  After the 10th oldest backup there should be kept:

  - 3 or 4 backups which are the newest on 3-4 prior weeks,
  - 11 monthly backups,
  - 1 yearly backup.

I can not use system date & time, I have to parse the filenames of the backups.
But eventually, date of the backups are provided.

My approach:
Because I can't know the schedule, which backup will happen on which day, I have to work with intervals, periods, stripes of dates. I need to determine relative ages of the backups after the 10th backup. This relative age is defined as the difference of days between the actual reference date (10th oldest date of backups) and the dates of backups before the 10th save.

I can do this, I read in filenames, parse date from `String`, get `Date` objects from these parsed Strings. I can put them into `Map<Path, Date>` (Later I also need `Set`'s no duplicate feature to get rid of the same dates [there can be several databases with same date but different name]). 
I can always determine the date of the 10th save, so I can get the reference `Date` object.
Therefore I can always calculate the relative age of a backup.
Relative ages of backups are unique and I can store a relative age with the `Date` from which it was calculated like this `TreeMap<Integer, Date>`.

I figure, I need to work with ranges of relative ages (`keySet()`). If I can determine the minimum and maximum relative ages in a range of relative age I can then filter the `Date` objects that are referenced by a relative age.
( `if relativeAge < 7`,`if relativeAge >= 7 & relativeAge < 14` and so on.) But I also have to rotate the `Dates`...

I can't wrap my head around this, any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Essentially, the problem is reduced to the following:

I have a list of integers. (List of relative ages): [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 24, 26...]

I have to create lower and upper boundaries to form groups of these integers. 
An integer, a relative age can be between 0 & 7 or 7 & 14, 14 & 21, 21 & 28, 28 & 56, 56 & 84 ... 336 & 364, and can be bigger than 364. I have to find integers that fall into these ranges respectively. After I found these groups of integers (a group might hold 0, 1 or more integers) I have to take the highest/oldest relative age in a certain range, group. If range is above 364, I will have to preserve lowest save, to stop yearly saves from accumulating.
I have to gather these highest relative ages in the above ranges and these will form a group of relative ages.

These relative ages reference unequivocally the dates of the backup files, so now I will know which date/file according to it should be preserved in the actual rotation.

I can interpret the notion of maximum relative age (maxRelAge) in a given rotation, that is the age of the oldest backup relative to the actual reference date.

I don't have to examine ranges of integers above the maximum relative age. After 1 year will the algorithm run in full extent.

But I still don't know how to code this algorithm in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question.

In order to implement the algorithm I put the list of integers into a `TreeSet`. I iterated over this set and checked whether an integer (a relative age) is in a range of relative ages, and if it is I collect them into another set, like this:

```
private void checkRelativeAge(TreeSet<Integer> ageGroup, int relAge, 
int boundary, int offset) {
    if (relAge > boundary & relAge <= boundary + offset) {
        ageGroup.add(relAge);
    }
}
```

This can be called several times while iterating over the relative ages:

```
checkRelativeAge(relAgesBetween336And364, relAge, 336, 28);
checkRelativeAge(relAgesBetween308And336, relAge, 308, 28);
checkRelativeAge(relAgesBetween280And308, relAge, 280, 28);
```

...

```
checkRelativeAge(relAgesBetween7And14, relAge, 7, 7);
checkRelativeAge(relAgesBetween1And7, relAge, 0, 7);
```

After I separated, collected relative ages into groups, I iterate over the relative ages again, examine whether a relative age is in a range, and if it is I take the last and first element of the range.

```
    if (relAge > boundary & relAge <= boundary + offset) {
        toBePreservedSet.add(dateRelativeAgeMap.get(ageGroup.last()));
        toBePreservedSet.add(dateRelativeAgeMap.get(ageGroup.first()));
    }
```

Finally, from the set `toBePreservedSet` I can relate to the dates to be preserved, respectively, and from dates I can relate back to the filenames and determine which to preserve and which to delete in a given rotation.